# Which Linux on my netbook?

Tags: lubuntu, system-installation

My netbook is an ACER AOD257. It has 1.66GHz, 1 GB of RAM and 320 GB HDD.

I am looking for the fastest Linux operative system on my computer. I have tried Lubuntu and I like it, but it is too much "cold" as operative system, then I have put Ubuntu; 12.04 LTS is the better version; is very fast and nice.

Nevertheless, I am facing another problem: my video card one is a half thunderstruck, 8 MB has gone to 128 MB, then inziavo to have problems also with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS because I had all the active effects.

Later I have passed to Ubuntu Mate 12.04, only that it gives me a problem, the audio is not heard... Then what operative System do you advise?

I would want it fast, nicely, lightly and very versatile. Has my friend advised me Ubuntu Studio, what do you think about it?

Comment: English please.

Comment: Per favore, usi l'inglese. Usi un servizio di traduzione automatica, come www.translate.ru o Google, e metta sia l'originale sia la traduzione allora la comunità può aiutare con la lingua inglese. -- Please use English. Use an automatic translation service, such as www.translate.ru or Google, and put both the original and translation so the community can help with the English language.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you try out [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/). Xubuntu is more lightweight than Ubuntu with Unity, but more polished than Lubuntu. If Lubuntu with LXDE worked fine for you (hardware-wise), then Xubuntu with Xfce should, too.

If Xubuntu doesn't suit you, though, then anoter solution could be [Enlightenment](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=about/e17&l=en). Either way, different people have different tastes, so I would suggest that you take a look at [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) for an overview of the various DEs available. Perhaps a different choice would fit your needs.

Comment: I've tried it, but I do not fully satisfy me ... You do not know anything more cute?

Comment: Tastes differ. I hear that some are crazy about Emacs these days, and the terminal can be an attractive environment. :) This said, see updated answer.